# Remove sub dir name from url

Tags: product, url

When I visit my website it shows `http://mywebsite.com/`.

When I view any product, url shows as `http://mywebsite.com/magento/productname/` where magento is my sub directory in which i installed magento.

What I want is, **remove `magento` from the url**.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

step one, go to your web root and move all the files within the magento sub directory from that folder to the web root itself.

step two, update the base URL in your database to reflect the change. In core_config_data, look for two rows where 'path' is 'web/unsecure/base_url' or 'web/secure/base_url'. Update both of those rows so 'value' is your URL but with magento removed from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't want my root directory over crowded.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting can manage multiple folders(other website folders) then through hosting panel you can select particular folder for specific website. Select your magento folder as root folder from hosting if you have access  **No need to move all files within magento subdirectory to web root.**

Then you need to remove magento from backend web url settings or `core_config_data` table field `'web/unsecure/base_url' AND/OR 'web/secure/base_url'`.